# Instantiate Freezing Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Attempting to create a grid of a simple circle gameobject as soon as the game starts. The space between each circle needs to be 1.41 and 1.34 in 2D. So with a little maths, I would have thought that this script would create this grid relative to an initial reference object.

However, upon clicking play in the editor, the game simply freezes and I have to kill Unity with my command prompt.

Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
void Awake()
{
    Transform transform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    for (float i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (float j = 1; j<8;j++)
        {
            Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position + new Vector3(i * 1.41f, 0, j * 1.34f), new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using the debugger then and step through the code I am sure it will freeze on the line that has the issue and or problem.. have you debugged this yet I would think that this `gameObject` should be replaced with `transform` since this is the newly created object instance in this line `Instantiate(gameObject,`

Comment: From this I think that the Awake function is running on every copy and is never getting past 1 on the iterator, looping endlessly, is there any way to stop this?

Comment: @JamesHughes You are right, this is called once on every copy so you just created infinite loop. Just seperate grid creation and your circle object.

Comment: @juniperi ahh thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Awake()
{
    Transform transform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    for (float i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (float j = 1; j<8;j++)
        {
            Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position + new Vector3(i * 1.41f, 0, j * 1.34f), new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Looking into your Instantantiate, you are using gameObject. This is the reference to the game object holding that script. So what you seem to be doing is instantiating a clone of that object. The newly created object is also triggering the loop, this will start a new process of creation and so on.

All in all, you created an endless loop. You need to create an instance of something else, a tile prefab most likely.

```
public GameObject myTilePrefab;
void Awake()
{
    Transform transform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    for (float i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (float j = 1; j<8;j++)
        {
            Instantiate(myTilePrefab, transform.position + new Vector3(i * 1.41f, 0, j * 1.34f), new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```